# Difficulty using Django All-Auth in my own project - url/migration problems

Tags: django, facebook, django-allauth

I'm having difficulty using Django-AllAuth in my own project, as the title suggests.  I'm using south, but am new to south, so that can be the source of my problems.  Below I'll detail the steps I took and where I am right now.

First, I moved the allauth folder to the root of the project.
Then, I moved the example code's templates to our startup app - I made the "plain/example/index.html" template our startup template (127.0.0.1:8000).

In our project's urls, I added:

```
#Allauth stuff:
url(r'^accounts/profile/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='plain/example/profile.html')),
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

And project settings look like this:

```
# Django settings for penguin project.
import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
# ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

db_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__),'..','..','..','db','peng.db'))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': db_path,# Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..', '..', 'static')).replace('\\','/'),
    )

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
    )

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = ''

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
    )

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'penguin.libs.utilities.import_middle.ImportXMLMiddleware',
    )

ROOT_URLCONF = 'penguin.urls'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'penguin.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    #absolute path, use / even on Windows
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','..')).replace('\\','/')
    )

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'penguin.apps.royal',
    'penguin.apps.blackboard',
    'penguin.libs.topic',
    'penguin.libs.sidebar',
    'penguin.libs.module',
    #'penguin.libs.users',
    'penguin.apps.messages',
    'penguin.apps.profiles',
    'penguin.libs.users',
    'south',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.dropbox',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.openid',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.persona',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.soundcloud',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.stackexchange',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitch',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.vimeo',
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.weibo',

    )

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",

    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
            },
        }
}
```

I syncdb, and I run the project.

When I try to go to social accounts on admin, though, I'm getting the following error:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/socialaccount/socialaccount/

no such table: socialaccount_socialaccount
```

I believe this problem is being caused by a problem with south.  When I syncdb, I get the following response:

```
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django.contrib.admin
 > penguin.apps.royal
 > penguin.apps.blackboard
 > penguin.libs.topic
 > penguin.libs.sidebar
 > penguin.libs.module
 > penguin.apps.messages
 > penguin.apps.profiles
 > penguin.libs.users
 > south
 > allauth
 > allauth.account

Not synced (use migrations):
 - allauth.socialaccount
 - allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook
```

As I am new to South (but have to use it for this project), I don't know how to solve this exactly.  I read online that I could do:

```
migrate socialaccount 0007 --fake
```

But after doing this, the problem persists.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem, or what causes it?  If anyone has any more questions, I can provide any information needed.

Comment: I believe the way it should work is you (1) do the syncdb for the core apps/south setup; then (2) do a non-fake 'migrate' to both (a) get those apps models defined in the DB and (b) update south's own DB-records of app/model/db state. So what happens if you try a non-fake 'migrate'? 

That said, there are apparently other errors with allauth's socialaccount app(s) and south migrations -- see https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/316 which also has a potential workaround for the fresh-project case (force syncdb --all and then migrate --fake).